# Sharepoint update metadata with Powershell problem with syntax?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, metadata

I am unable to update the date and capital letters on my sharepoint via powershella script. All the others work, only this one doesn't work.
Can you help me? I have been tired for several hours.

My sharepoint metadata:

[image]

My script for update metadata in Sharepoint.

[image]

Thank you so much for help

Comment: What's the two fields' type ?  DATA_AUDYTU is a  date column ?

Comment: yes, DATA_AUDYTU is date, 

NAZWA_SIECI - is text with uppercase letters

Answer (score 0):

I tested DATA_AUDYTU as Date field, NAZWA_SIECI as Single Line Text field in my side with the sample code snippet below, it's working as expected:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
  
#Set parameter values
$SiteURL="https://Tenant.sharepoint.com"
$FileRelativeUrl="/doc2/test.txt"
 
Try {
        #Get Credentials to connect
        $Cred= Get-Credential
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
  
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
 
        $File = $Ctx.web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($FileRelativeUrl)
        $Ctx.Load($File)
        $Ctx.Load($File.ListItemAllFields)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 
        #Set Metadata of the File
        $ListItem = $File.ListItemAllFields
        $Listitem["NAZWA_SIECI"] = "TEST"
        $Listitem["DATA_AUDYTU"]="12/24/2020"
        $ListItem.Update()
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 
        Write-host -f Green "File's Metadata has been Updated Successfully!"
     }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Updating Metadata of the File!" $_.Exception.Message
   }
```

[image]

Column details:

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show my your setting for columns?

Comment: Add column screen capture in the answer, please check.

Comment: @MałgorzataUrbańska, is there any update ? Have you worked out  the problem ?

Comment: I removed columns from sharepoint and i created again... and works :). Your script did not work for me, but i when i removed and add again columns in sp = works @Jerry_MSFT

Comment: Thank you so much for help.

Comment: @MałgorzataUrbańska, actually, I'm assuming the column you are using in SharePoint will have a bit problem, as the same script is working in my side. Finally, you recreate the column and it solved the problem. Great to hear this information, you could accept as answer to close this question now :)